# Get MVC form field name with Html.FieldNameFor() defined by Orchard CMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, orchardcms

I want to generate form field names based on Html.FieldNameFor() but i'm not sure whether that works with my view model. The `ViewModel` looks like

```
public class FieldsModel
{
  public string Caption { get; set; }
}

public class FormModel
{
  public FieldsModel Fields { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
  public FormModel Form { get; set; }
}
```

How do i write the Linq lamda expression so that Razor understands it?

Obviously something like

```
@Html.FieldNameFor(model.Form.Fields => Caption)
```

does not work.

Update:
To be clear, i need to get `Caption` from that function call.

Comment: Why dont you try like below.

Comment: i have never heard of `@Html.FieldNameFor()` is this is your custom html helper method?

Comment: @Aravindan I don't need to try (although i did desperately) as it's not a valid lamda expression.

Comment: @Kartikeya Oh my, it's an extension method for HtmlHelper defined by the Orchard CMS in Orchard.Mvc.Html. I thought it's standard MVC, my bad.

Comment: try `@Html.FieldNameFor(model=>model.Form.Fields.Caption)`

Comment: @Kartikeya Nope, first you need to write `@Html.FieldNameFor(model => model.Form.Fields.Caption)` or Razor won't understand it and then it returns `Form.Fields.Caption`. I just need the field name `Caption`.

Comment: Instead of `@Html.FieldNameFor(model => model.Form.Fields.Caption)` use `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Form.Fields.Caption)`

Comment: @Kartikeya Yeah, that would be a workaround as it just returns the name assigned via data annotations attribute.

Comment: It would be useful to say how it doesn't work, but I'm going to assume that it complains about dynamically dispatching a Lambda. Basically, if you have a dynamic model, the Lambda-based helpers can't be used, unless you do some casting first, but then you need to build your own HtmlHelper instance, which is possible but not super-easy. Your best bet is to  use the non-Lambda helpers, in this case that's probably `@Html.FieldName("Form.Fields.Caption")`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model.Form.Fields.Caption)
```

It will gives the fields name exactly.

Comment: Nope, first you need to write `@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Form.Fields.Caption)` or Razor won't understand it and then it returns `<label for="Form_Fields_Caption">Caption</label>`. I just need the field name `Caption`.

Comment: Here in above code I used ID for please try that one, I tested it works good. let know once you get it.

Comment: `Html.IdFor<>()` is a templatized version of `Html.Id()` and it returns the ID based on the model used by the view which is `ViewModel` not `FieldsModel`, hence the ID is `Form_Fields_Caption` instead of `Caption`.